# Typo3 backend not multilanguest

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

In typoscript I have setup my website to support three languages. In the frontend it is working fine but  in the backend i'm missing the dropdown selection for "languages"? Only "Columns" and "Quickedit" are visible. How can i enable the "languages" selection in the BE?

I used this typoscript to set it up:

```html
page.config.linkVars = L
page.config.uniqueLinkVars = 1
page.config.sys_language_overlay = content_fallback
page.config.language = nl
page.config.locale_all = nl_NL
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = nl-NL
page.config.sys_language_uid = 0
[browser = msie]
page.config.htmlTag_setParams = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v=”urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml” xml:lang="nl"

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
page.config.language = en
page.config.locale_all = en_EN
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = en-EN
page.config.sys_language_uid = 1
[globalVar = GP:L = 1] && [browser = msie]
page.config.htmlTag_setParams = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v=”urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml” xml:lang="en"

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
page.config.language = de
page.config.locale_all = de_DE
page.config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
page.config.sys_language_uid = 2
[globalVar = GP:L = 2] && [browser = msie]
page.config.htmlTag_setParams = xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v=”urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml” xml:lang="de"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Order to be able to translate content in the backend into e.g. english you need to

1. Go to your Root page (ID=0), select the list module and create a
   'Website Language' Record 'english'.
2. Go to the page you want to translate and create a record called
   'Alternative Page Language'. Choose 'english' as Language.
3. You should now see a translation option in the discribed dropdown.
4. Repeat for as many pages and languages as you need.

Edit: You can see how this is done in this (german) video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62ZuTYRKq5U

Comment: Making the Alternative language pages was succeeded. Only the is no dropdown list item for the language. If I look at one of the alternative language records I saw that that language has the value: [INVALID VALUE("1")]. Look like the BE does nog know the language names in combination with its value and therefore not shown in the dropdown menu?

Comment: NO it means the 'Website Language' with UID 1 was not found. Please do Step 1 as I suggested.

Comment: Daniel thanks for the replay. But if I look in list view under the root page and then create new record. These is no "Website Language" record to create?

Comment: This has to be done on the topmost Page (ID=0) not on a page just marked as a root page.

Comment: See the YT video for reference.

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed. I did look at the root of a website not the topmost page as you mentioned.